Can I remove /var/lib/docker/aufs?
My situation is that the server I'm running is at least 5 years old and at some point I upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04. I know you should not touch /var/lib/docker (here just ./) contents but it seems docker has left the ./aufs folder untouched since the upgrade and it using 85G.
Running docker volume ls --format {{.Mountpoint}} it shows only folders in ./volumes nothing in ./aufs. While ./aufs has 85G, there is also a ./overlay2 folder with 25G and the ./volumes folder has only 5G.
I'm confused now. If we should not touch this folder should docker not clean up unused stuff from old installations? I remember that there was an issue after the upgrade that all containers had to be recreated and I think we had to change to overlay2. But why docker reports all volumes in ./volumes and nothing in ./overlay2 then? Can I trust that output, or is it using the data somewhere else?

https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/system/prune/ Usually prune will clean up but there is one other option IIRC, but I am unsure atm which it is.

The aufs driver was deprecated by Docker. If you run docker info, you should see overlay2 listed as the storage driver.
Assuming you see overlay2 in docker info, unless you know there's data in there you want to try retrieving (either manually or using an older docker install), it should be safe to delete. I would start by renaming the directory and verifying you can restart docker before permanently removing it.
